# jQuery looping section of an animation - update: sample animation

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop, repeat

I am trying to loop a sections of an animation but not having any luck. I have tried a few suggestions from other forum but it does not seem to work.

Can someone please give me a few pointers. Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**: Here is a sample animation on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKkN/)

```
$(window).load(function() {

$("#Div1").animate({
"top": "0px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div2").animate({
"top": "0px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
$("#Div3").animate({
"top": "0px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div4").animate({
"top": "0px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

// Repeat from here //
!function repeat() {

$("#Div1").delay(5000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div5").delay(5000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div2").delay(10000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div6").delay(10000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div3").delay(13000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div7").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "-300px"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo')

$("#Div1").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div5").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div2").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div6").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div3").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');

$("#Div7").delay(15000).animate({
"top": "0"
}, 2000, 'easeOutExpo')

}

 $(document).ready(function() {
 repeat();
});

});
});
```

Comment: I'm having a little issue understanding what you are trying to achieve could you possible give us a link or jsfiddle to help you out?

Comment: Thanks Toby. What I am trying to do is once the animation goes to the end of the code, I would like it to repeat from the comment line (// Repeat from here //) again and again infinitely. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* here is a working example of your animation with a `setTimeout()` function. Try this and let me know if it works for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKkN/1/)**

JS:

```
    // Repeat mark - repeat from here once it ends
    (function repeat(){

        $("#Div1").delay(2000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div5").delay(2000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');


        $("#Div2").delay(4000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div6").delay(4000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');


        $("#Div3").delay(6000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div7").delay(6000).animate({
            "top": "-100px"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo')


        $("#Div1").delay(8000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div5").delay(8000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');


        $("#Div2").delay(10000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div6").delay(10000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');


        $("#Div3").delay(11000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        $("#Div7").delay(12000).animate({
            "top": "0"
        }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');

        setTimeout(function(){
            repeat();
        },12000);
    })();
    // Repeat and go to Repeat mark
```

Comment: Here is a sample animation without the repeat function since I could not get it to work. I did put a comment marker where it needs to repeat. Thanks for taking a look. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKkN/)

Comment: badAdviceGuy, thanks but the animation sequence goes not work as before :(

Comment: I don't understand what isn't working, did you look at the fiddle I provided? It works there with the complete code.

Comment: The sequence has changed. It does not work the same as the original if look at mine and then yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a mess, so many different speeds, delays, elements etc. it's really hard to join it together. There must be an easier to way to do this, but the best I could come up with was something like

```
$(function() {
    $("#Div1, #Div2").animate({
        "top": "0px"
    }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo', function () {
        $("#Div3, #Div4").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        (function fn() {
            $.when(
                $('#Div1, #Div5').delay(5000).animate({
                    "top": "-300px"
                }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo'),
                $("#Div2, #Div6").delay(10000).animate({
                    "top": "-300px"
                }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo'),
                $("#Div3").delay(13000).animate({
                    "top": "-300px"
                }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo'),
                $("#Div7").delay(15000).animate({
                    "top": "-300px"
                }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo'),
                $('#Div1, #Div2, #Div3, #Div5, #Div6, #Div7').animate({
                    "top": "0"
                }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo')
            ).done(fn);
        })();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ATDnn/)

Comment: adeneo, I wish I had better programming skills as I have very little knowledge. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Phillip - There's nothing really wrong with your coding, what I really mean is that when you have so many different variables it's hard to see how it all fits together, and how to make it work as good as possible with the least amount of repetition etc.

Comment: adeneo, ok I will try to construct a jFiddle sample. Thanks